# Check if new post or update before save_post action

Tags: save-post

I want to use save_post on an update for an existing post and also for a new post, but I want 2 different "priority" on the save_post action.

So, I can't check if it's an update into save_post function parameter, I have to check this before save_post.

How can I do this ?

Thanks

Ps: I want something like this :

```
add_action('save_post', function ($post_ID, WP_Post $post) {
//Do something when it's an update }, 9, 2 );


add_action('save_post', function ($post_ID, WP_Post $post) {
//Do something when it's a new post }, 11, 2 );
```

Comment: The `save_post` hook has a 3rd parameter, namely [`$update`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post/#parameters), so why not use an if-else from within a single callback to check whether it's an update or a new post? Why do you need two different priorities?

Comment: I already saw about $update parameter, but it will not affect priority parameter. I have to make a condition before being in save_post.

Comment: Out of curiousity what are you doing here? What's the priority 10 action you need to be the correct side of?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using the wp_insert_post hook, which is called before the post is saved or updated. Inside this hook, you can check if the post ID exists to determine if it's an update or a new post. Here's how you can do it:

```
        add_action('wp_insert_post', function ($post_ID, $post, $update) {
        if (!$update) {
            // This is a new post
            add_action('save_post', function ($post_ID, $post) {
                // Do something when it's a new post
            }, 11, 2);
        } else {
            // This is an update
            add_action('save_post', function ($post_ID, $post) {
                // Do something when it's an update
            }, 9, 2);
        }
    }, 10, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could register both and test the $update parameter before doing anything:

```php
add_action('save_post', function ($post_ID, WP_Post $post, $update) {
    if (!$update) return;
    //Do something when it's an update
}, 9, 3 );

add_action('save_post', function ($post_ID, WP_Post $post, $update) {
    if ($update) return;
    //Do something when it's a new post
}, 11, 3 );
```